# Predicting future price from sales data

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models

I want to be able to predict what a product's price would be based on its current sales listings and its sales history.

The historical sales data would be a list of (date, price, quantity)

The current listings data would be a list of (price, quantity)

A very simple idea would be just to calculate the average quantity sold per day from the sales data(say, for the past week) and assume the same amount will be sold tomorrow. Then, we can remove that quantity from the listings data sorted by price ascending, and predict the new price of this project to be the new lowest listing price.

Obviously this does not account for stuff such as price elasticity, demand trends, etc.

Just wondering if anybody had any ideas/leads on how I can figure out better ways to solve this problem